# Word referring to process of curing meats?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, vocabulary

I remember watching an episode of *Floyd on France* some time ago which described a French town as famous for their cured meats. I believe the word began with an 'H', and referred to the process of curing meat. If anyone could remember the term, I would sleep easier.

Comment: Are you looking for [*charcuterie*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charcuterie)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charcuterie.
From French : chair 'flesh' & cuit 'cooked'.

Reference : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charcuterie

Comment: How much more useful, and *helpful* to the asker, if you had  provided a clear definition of the said word. And *that* way you would have filled the minimum number of characters.

Comment: @Mari-LouA , just so your comment still makes sense to future readers , I edited the answer to make it more helpful and complete.

Comment: @Prem you're too good a person, you must be new to EL&U! :-)

Comment: @Mari-LouA , thanks for your compliment ! Yes, I am relatively new here, atleast in terms of active usage !

Comment: I beleive that's what I'm looking for! Thanks very much.